# What does it means on javascript? " /** @type {HTMLElement} */ "

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, backend

My code

```
  #color;
  #validColors;
  constructor(element, validColors = []) {
    /** @type {HTMLElement} */ <----- This one is what i'm refering in the headline
    this.element = element;
    this.#color = validColors[0];
    this.#validColors = validColors;
```

Comment: This means that the element is an html element like button, textarea, input

Comment: That’s just a comment, following JSdoc format. See https://jsdoc.app/tags-type.html

Comment: HTMLElement is the parent element of every HTML element (button, paragraph, list, div, etc). You can read more about it on the MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement